# Confirmation box when submitting post for review

Tags: posts, php, jquery

A very common issue that I experience with new authors is that they forget to complete a few essential tasks prior to submitting their post for review (even though I have a guide available for them).

Is it possible to add a confirmation box that appear only when a contributor clicks on the "Submit for Review" button? Potentially a jQuery box like this:

[image]

I have come across a few confirm publish codes on the [web](http://blog.plasticmind.com/wordpress/wordpress-publish-confirmation/) and [plugin archives](http://wordpress.org/plugins/confirm-publishing-actions/) but all of which trigger on *Publish* (not *Submit for Review*) and prompts a Javascript alert window.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A useful fast way is to use JavaScript in combination with an Ajax action that outputs the box.

Create a small plugin. Create a folder inside plugins directory, naming it 'SubmitReviewConf'. In this folder create a PHP file named `SubmitReviewConf.php`.

In this file, put this code:

```
<?php
/**
* Plugin Name: Submit for Review Confirmation Message
* Description: Confirmation Message for Submit for Review Action
* Author: G.M.
*/

function add_my_admin_assets( $hook ) {
    // Only once variable force the box to be shown only one time. Can be from theme or plugin via filter.
    // Default is true
    $only_once = apply_filters( 'submit_review_conf_onlyonce', 1 );
    //
    if ( $only_once && $hook == 'post.php' ) $post = get_post( $_GET['post'] );
    $enqueue = $only_once ? ($hook == 'post-new.php' || ( $hook == 'post.php' && $post->post_status != 'pending') ) : ($hook == 'post-new.php' || $hook == 'post.php');
    if ( isset($post) && get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_skip_SubmitReviewConf', true ) ) return;
    $postid = '';
    if ( isset($_GET['post']) && is_object($post) ) $postid = $post->ID;
    if ( $enqueue && ! current_user_can( 'edit_published_posts' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'thickbox' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'SubmitReviewConf', plugins_url( 'SubmitReviewConf.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery','thickbox' ), null );
        wp_localize_script( 'SubmitReviewConf', 'SubmitReviewConfData', array( 'only_once' => $only_once, 'postid' => $postid ) );
    } 
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_admin_assets', 30 );

function clean_up_SubmitReviewConf_meta( $post ) {
     delete_post_meta( $post->ID, '_skip_SubmitReviewConf' );
}
add_action( 'pending_to_publish', 'clean_up_SubmitReviewConf_meta', 30 );      

function confirmation_msg_out() {
    if ( isset( $_GET['only_once'] ) && isset( $_GET['postid'] ) ) update_post_meta( $_GET['postid'], '_skip_SubmitReviewConf', '1' );
    // SET HTML FOR THE CONFIRMATION MESSAGE IN THIS FUNCTION
    ?>
    <div id="confirmation_msg_out">
        <ul>
            <li><?php _e('Did you ... '); ?></li>
            <li><?php _e('Did you ... '); ?></li>
            <li><?php _e('Did you ... '); ?></li>
        </ul>
        <input id="confirmation_msg_submit" class="button button-primary button-large" value="<?php _e('Submit for Review') ?>" name="submitforreview"></input>
        <a id="confirmation_msg_submit_cancel" class="button button-large" href="#"><?php _e('Cancel') ?></a>
    </div>
    <?php
    die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_output_review_confirm', 'confirmation_msg_out' );
```

This small plugin contains only 2 functions. ( Edit: after an OP request in comments, it became 3)

The first enqueues a custom script (what is it is explained later) and the 'thickbox' script (the script WordPress uses to show modal messages).

These scripts are enqueued only if current user cannot edit published posts, so authors and *higher* users can publish posts with no confirmation message.

The second function outputs the HTML for the confirmation box. This function is hooked into an Ajax action, `output_review_confirm`.

Now in the same folder of PHP files let's create our JavaScript file and name it `SubmitReviewConf.js`.

In this file put:

```
jQuery().ready( function($) {

    var $publish = $('#publish');

    var only_once = SubmitReviewConfData.only_once;

    function remove_confirm_publish_button() {
        $('#confirm-publish-button').remove();
        $publish.show();
    }

    $(document).on('click', '#confirm-publish-button', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ( only_once ) remove_confirm_publish_button();
        var tb_show_url = ajaxurl + '?action=output_review_confirm';
        if (only_once) tb_show_url += "&only_once=1";
        if ( SubmitReviewConfData.postid != '' ) tb_show_url += "&postid=" + 
            SubmitReviewConfData.postid;
        tb_show('', tb_show_url);
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#confirmation_msg_submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        tb_remove();
        $publish.click();
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#confirmation_msg_submit_cancel', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        tb_remove();
    });

    var newbutton = '<input id="confirm-publish-button" class="button button-primary button-large" type="button" value="' + 
        $publish.val() + '"></input>';
    $publish.hide().after(newbutton);

});
```

What this script does:

1. Hides the WordPress 'Submit for Review' button and replaces it with a button that appears equal to the WP one, but that does not trigger the submit action.
2. When our *fake* submit button is clicked, we use the Ajax URL to trigger our function and output the HTML inside the modal confirmation, using the `tb_show` function provided by the ThickBox script.
3. When the user clicks 'Submit for Review' inside the modal box, we simulate a click on the WP standard 'Submit for Review' button and remove the modal window. If the user clicks on 'Cancel' we simply remove the modal window, doing nothing.

That's all. Remember to activate the plugin in WP backend ;)

Note that this plugin requires JavaScript to be enabled on user browser. If disabled the user will not see any confirmation, but consider that modal window (ThickBox) is a JavaScript script that cannot work if JavaScript is disabled.

If this feature was a critical one, you'd probably want to disable publishing if JavaScript is disabled, but being a not-critical feature, you can just ignore users that have JavaScript disabled (WordPress will take care for your security, in that case) considering they are a very small percentage of users.

Comment: Before I praise you for this solution, let us make it work accordingly. Currently upon plugin activation, this error appears: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in /SubmitReviewConf/SubmitReviewConf.php on line 30

Comment: Sworn that I did that, at least when I pasted it in phpStorm. Nonetheless, this is a stellar answer and works very elegantly. Very well done! I will leave the question open for a few days so the answer receives more attention (upvotes) which I certainly believe that it deserves. With that being said, I do have a final question. Like many other multi-author platforms, I use WyPiekacz http://wordpress.org/plugins/wypiekacz/ which is a plugin where you can set conditions that users need to follow when posting.

Comment: Problem is that the broken rule notification appears *after* the thickbox appears. Making this a very painful task if the user have to see the thickbox several times- which could potentially make this an annoyance rather than a benefit. Is there any way to enforce these rules *first* and when they are passed, then display the thickbox?

Comment: @ChristineCooper The problem is that your plugin check rules on `wp_insert_post_data` filter. So if post pass rules, post is saved very soon, and I think there is no chance to show the modal box before post is saved as 'pending'... An easy edit I can make to my plugin is to force modal box appear only one time, but still *before* rules are passed or *after* post is already sended for review.

Comment: I completely understand and expected as such, which is why I thought I would get your input. If possible though, can you please update your answer with the one-time fix (before rules are passed) which will definitely be useful.

Comment: @ChristineCooper. Ok, now the plugin show modal box only one time, on post creation. Note that to accomplish this I've changed both php and js files. The only once behavior can be changed via filter in theme or in another plugin. Just to make things _elegantly_ :)

Comment: Excellent! However I may have found a major bug. Do the following in this order: Add new post, write random text, click 'Save Draft' button, and then click 'Submit for review'. When doing that, the box doesn't appear. It does appear if you click submit without saving draft. The problem is that all users work on their articles and save drafts prior to submitting it. Do you have a fix for this?

Comment: @ChristineCooper _"Do you have a fix for this?"_ Is this a challenge? ;D Solve bug was very easy for itself, problem is compatibility with WyPiekacz. Only for that I have to implement additional code handling a meta field. Btw now bug should be fixed in WyPiekacz compatible way. Only check this workflow: (I haven't WyPiekacz to test): create and save post as draft. After saved change it in a way that make WyPiekacz rules fail. Send for review, modal should appear. In modal click 'Submit' this will trigger WyPiekacz error. Correct it and send for review again. Does modal appear again?

Comment: I did your steps and it works as it should. The *only* scenario when it reappears is if you fail the WyPiekacz twice in a row. Not three times though. But this is perfectly fine, I would actually prefer that it appears twice if they fail the conditions because clearly they have not checked the guidelines prior to submitting :) G.M. This is a stellar answer! Thank you very much for taking your to write it and rewrite it. This will be handy for me and *many* others! I will leave this question open until the bounty runs out. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do so. You have to use the `wp_insert_post_data` filter hook. I will give you the general idea, hopefully this helps.

An example would be:

```
function my_filter_handler($data , $postarr) {
    // do something with the post data

    // You have to check that your post is submitted for review, not the publish post, so you have to have an if statement checking that

    // Then, you have to ensure that you use jQuery that comes with WordPress (using enqueue methods), and not a jQuery you supply.

    return $data;
}

add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'my_filter_handler', '99', 2 );
```

Comment: By the way, another approach would be to use the 'save_post' action hook instead of the wp_insert_post_data filter hook. Just so you have different ideas.